# Detailed definition of the Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I have a basic definition of the Monotone Convergence Theorem:

> If $\{X_n\}_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of random variables such that $X_n\nearrow X$ **pointwise** and $X_n\ge 0\ \forall n$, then $E(X_n)\nearrow E(X)$.

My question , how much liberality can made on the convergence part? I mean: which of these (namely - **almost sure** convergence , convergence **in proability** , $\&$ convergence **in distribution**) can be placed in place of the **pointwise** conergence and still the definition remains exactly same?

Comment: Almost sure. Consider the collection of points $A$ under which it surely converges, which has probability 1, and then use the MCT to achieve $E(X_n1_A)\uparrow E(X1_A)$, and apply $P(X=Y)=1$ implies $EX=EY$.

Comment: @NickC What about the others? Can you throw dome light?

Comment: How would you define monotone convergence in probability or in distribution (the monotone part?)?

Comment: @JimmyR. Can you please explain your doubt better?

Comment: Yes. When you say $X_n \nearrow X$ pointwise, then you mean that for every $ω\in Ω$: $X_n(ω)\le X_{n+1}(ω)\le .... \nearrow X(ω)$. But if $X_n$ to $X$ in probability, then how would you compare $X_n$ and $X_{n+1}$ to say that $X_n\le X_{n+1}\le ...$? Because here you have $P(|X_n-X|>ε)\to 0$ as a definition of convergence in probability.

Comment: @JimmyR. Only change will be that $|X_n-X|$ will always be equal to $X-X_n$ if $X_n$ **increases** to $X$, i.e. We will then say $P(X-X_n>\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$ if $X_n $ increases to $X$ with convergence in probability.

Comment: But when you say $X_n$ increases to $X$, you assume again pointwise convergence and not only convergence in probability.

Comment: @qwerty: I think your question might sound a bit vague as, effectively, the convergence of the sequence $X_n$ to $X$ is not an assumption of the MCT. Indeed, if $X_n$ is increasing a.s. then it is a.s. convergent. So, in this case, the statement $X_n \nearrow X$ says that $X_n$ is increasing and it's limit is denoted with $X$.